# Securing CentOS /boot readonly breaks system on reboot

Tags: boot

I'm hardening a CentOS system and i found a page where it states that the /boot should be read only which is ok by using:

```
LABEL=/boot     /boot     ext2     defaults,ro     1 2
```

But if i reboot the system it cannot boot because: fsck.ext2: unable to resolve 'LABEL=/boot/'
My fstab looks like this:

```
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=c4ed104b-ce03-4ede-9740-22bede0d058e /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
#LABEL=/boot            /boot                   ext2    defaults,ro     1 2
```

Is this a good practice? if so how can i do it properly

Comment: This might help you understand the issues. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88036/what-is-the-effect-of-setting-immutable-bit-on-boot-partition You need to fsck that partition and thus change it from read only to writable. After that, if required, you can reset to read only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the error message, I would say your boot partition isn't labeled /boot.

You're already mounting it previously anyway, so just add your options to that line. For example :

```
UID=c4ed104b-ce03-4ede-9740-22bede0d058e /boot ext4 defaults,ro 1 2
```

Instead of read only I would put `noauto`, so that it isn't mounted at boot but has to be mounted manually with `mount /boot`.